# List of parent structure groups from a page using Core service

Tags: core-service, structuregroups

Please let me know how to get the list of parent structure groups from the given page id using core service 2013?

I was try to use below code in my workflow automatic activity to get the page detail but it was giving error:

```
var tridionItems = CoreServiceClient.GetListXml(workitem.Subject.IdRef, new RepositoryItemsFilterData { ItemTypes = new[] { cs.ItemType.StructureGroup } });
```

Error Message:

```
Unexpected item type: Page.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService.GetListXml(String id, SubjectRelatedListFilterData filter)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.SessionAwareCoreServiceClient.GetListXml(String id, SubjectRelatedListFilterData filter)
   at Workflow.SkipApproval.Execute()
```

Comment: Vivek - you should show what you've tried here first so people don't spend all their time re-inventing the wheel. have you looked at the API? did you see/try anything that you thought _should_ work? (post the code as an example - maybe your syntax needs review). Have you searched TREX - this is *not* the first time this question has been asked.

Comment: Do you mean a recursive list up to the root Structure Group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `OrganizationalItemAncestorsFilterData`

The CoreService API reference (which you can download from [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF)) has a good example on how to do this:

```
OrganizationalItemAncestorsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemAncestorsFilterData();
IEnumerable<IdentifiableObjectData> list = client.GetList("tcm:1-2-64", filter);
```

Comment: Thanks Nuno your provided solutions works for providing recursive list up to the root Structure Group.

Answer (score 0):

As Nuno suggested you should use OrganizationalItemAncestorsFilterData filter instead of Repository item filters.

If you are looking for path till root structure group do the following-
PageData pageData= (PageData)client.Read(pageTCM, new ReadOptions());
string pageLocation = pageData.LocationInfo.Path.ToString();

Also you can extract Structure Group name from the path if you want.

Thanks